can we develop an indicator which only shows a particular day on the chart?
I want to see only the bar of a particular day on trading view
I am from a non-coding background so couldn't try much. I Have searched google and tried diff indicators made by users but couldn't find what I was looking for.

You can use timestamp() and plotcandle() functions for that. However, you also need to disable the original candles from the settings.
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

time_in_window = (time >= timestamp("20 Apr 2024 00:00")) and (time <= timestamp("21 Apr 2024 00:00"))

candle_is_green = (close >= open)
candle_col = candle_is_green ? color.green : color.red

float c_open = time_in_window ? open : na
float c_high = time_in_window ? high : na
float c_low = time_in_window ? low : na
float c_close = time_in_window ? close : na

plotcandle(c_open, c_high, c_low, c_close, "My Candle", candle_col, candle_col, bordercolor=candle_col)



Thanks for the response. I think i was not able to convey my issue. For example if we have a Nifty chart on a Daily tf, I only want to see bars of thursdays. How do I address this thing?
